# How to extract one-dimensional array from Two dimensional array in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

H
I'm using VB.NET, and i have a two dimensional array. 
How do I extract a one-dimensional array from it? I.E the 3rd row.

Something like MAT[0] which i would do in java to get the first row from a matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code fragment where you define the 2 dimensional array?

Comment: Public RXUser_Array(14, 257) As Byte.
That's how it's declared.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use parenthesis instead ob brackets:

```
mat(0)
```

Comment: Tried that. It says "number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array"

Comment: Sorry. is's mat(0)(0) or the index you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write a simple function to get a single row as an array, for example:

```
Private Function GetRow(matrix As Byte(,), row_number As Integer) As Byte()
    'get the number of columns of your matrix
    Dim number_of_columns As Integer = matrix.GetLength(1)

    'define empty array, at the end of the 'for' cycle it will contain requested row's values  
    Dim values As Byte() = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 0 To number_of_columns - 1
        'Resize array
        ReDim Preserve values(i)
        'Populate array element
        values(i) = matrix(row_number, i)
    Next

    Return values

End Function
```